# Javascript. How to show a animation before swf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject

I'm showing SWF files by swfObject plugin.

I want to show a div with a animation, for 3 seconds, and only than, after the animation finished(3 seconds after the div is load), show the swf.

How should I do that ? Sorry for the foolishness.

Example to the site: http://only4gamer.com/games/game/Retro-Assault

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest using Javascript. Now go write some code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jQuery installed, this could be done fairly simply.

```
function animationComplete(){
   //Do Stuff
}
$("div").animate({width : 200, height: 500}, 3000, animationComplete)
```

- This represents the animation you wish to run: {width : 200, height: 500}
- This is three thousand milliseconds (3 seconds): 3000
- This is the function to run after the animation is complete: animationComplete